# Using one GLSL shader program for textured and untextured rendering?

Tags: opengl, c++, shaders, glsl

Rather than have two separate shaders in my OpenGL code (one for when a texture is bound, one for when none is bound) I usually go for one shader program which handles both.  This is my usual fragment shader:

```
#version 330

uniform bool textured;
uniform sampler2D sampler;

in vec4 fColor;
in vec2 tCoord;

out vec4 final_color;

void main()
{
    vec4 texel = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    if (textured)
        texel = texture(sampler, tCoord);
    final_color = fColor * texel;
}
```

In a modern OpenGL profile, this compiled but did not output anything but black pixels (alternatively in LWJGL legacy profile, it outputted regular colors if textured == false and textured if textured == true).  I don't see any reason that this *wouldn't* work, but what is a method which would work for both textured and untextured fragments?

**EDIT:**

- [My Shader Class](http://pastebin.com/YdBRgvAd)
- [My Main CPP File](http://pastebin.com/5jb6w5ei)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't bind a texture to the slot, the result of sampling is basically undefined (though it's often `vec4(0)`).

To fix your issue, create a white 1x1 texture and assign it to `sampler` when you're using this shader without a texture.

Comment: Even though I only reference it if `textured == true`?

Comment: @ZachGoethel Ah, missed that, sorry. In that case, there could easily be a bug in the `textured` uniform setting code. But there could also be undefined behavior (shader compiles to mix(texel, texture(..), textured), texture returns NaN). Either way, the approach I described works without the branch and extra parameter.

Comment: But do you have recommended changes? To set `textured` I use `glUniform1i([location getter], 0 or 1)`.

Comment: @ZachGoethel There's nothing to change there. But have you actually checked that the code runs, and at the right time (after glUseProgram, before the draw call)? P.S. http://stackoverflow.com/a/21030831/1648140

Comment: I'm adding links to my main.cpp and shader.hpp, but I won't be able to add more until tomorrow afternoon.

Comment: @ZachGoethel Shader usage looks fine, though I couldn't tell from the code if anything should be visible on screen. If clear color is black and rendered object appears to be black as well, it could instead be invisible (there's no visual difference), and there are many possible reasons for anything to be invisible in OpenGL.

Comment: If I remove the offending texturing code, it renders an RGB triangle.  Odd issue: if I comment it out instead, it still doesn't work. (Wut?)

Comment: I'm going to accept your answer since I believe it will work.  Thank you for your help with this!